# Ruby on Rails how to create multiple buttons for starting and stopping a program

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, centos7

I'm trying to create an application on Linux CentOS 7 using Ruby on Rails (Ruby 2.4.1 & Rails 5.2.0) where it displays a program that's running and gives you several buttons to stop or start the program. Would I do this in a form or would this be some other kind of process? I've looked this up for a while and couldn't find an answer. I'm also not sure how to send this code to start or stop the program, but I'm guessing I will need JavaScript for this task.

This is the code I've gotten from the Getting Started with Rails tutorial:

```
<%= form_with scope: :article, url: articles_path, local: true do |form| %>
  <p>
    <%= form.label :title %><br>
    <%= form.text_field :title %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= form.label :text %><br>
    <%= form.text_area :text %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= form.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.2/getting_started.html

However, I don't know how to put a button outside of a submit button like this, and I cannot edit the text on the button's label. Also, to reiterate, I'm not sure if a form is what's needed for this task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't need a form. Just do something like

```
<%= link_to "Start", your_start_url, id: 'start-button', class: 'btn btn-primary', remote: true %>
```

and

```
<%= link_to "Stop", your_stop_url, id: 'stop-button', class: 'btn btn-danger', remote: true %>
```

You can style the links to look like a button. Of, if you're using Bootstrap, then Bootstrap will do the styling for you.

You probably want to set the `disabled` class for the links depending on whether the program is currently running or not. Given `remote: true`, you can use JS to reset the `disabled` class based on what the user clicks (using an `.on 'click'` or `.click` handler).

I suppose you could do this entirely on the front end. In which case you might do something like:

```
<div id: 'start-button', class: 'btn btn-primary'></div>
```

And then in your JS, you could do something like (using JQuery and coffescript):

```
$('#start-button').on 'click', (e) =>
  # do some stuff
```

Personally, I prefer to handle stuff like third party programs on the back end. But, skin the cat however you prefer.

Comment: Would I still use URLs for starting/stopping an external program?

Comment: Yes, because the link is on the front end. The URL will point the link to the correction `Controller#action` on the back end, where you can interact with the external program. I suppose you *could* do this entirely on the front end, but that's a matter of preference, I guess.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Would the URL point to a JavaScript file that undergoes the actions? would this JS go in the controllers folder or would it be in the current HTML file? Sorry, I'm new to this.

Comment: If you're using the `link_to` approach, the URL points to a route that you've defined in `routes.rb`. Your decisions regarding javascript (that handles either the remote `link_to` or `on. 'click'`) are subject to personal preferences. Some people use `js.erb` (I **never ever** use `js.erb`). Other people put the js in views. I use JQuery and a lot of my js is developed as JQuery plugins. That's a much broader topic. Are you coding as a student? A hobby? For work?

Comment: I'm coding for work. It's pretty much like an internship. I've just dug into the assets folder and realized that's where the js scripts and stylesheets are supposed to be edited, so that makes things easier. I'm slowly starting to understand how all the directories work together in Ruby on Rails apps, but still unsure exactly how the MVC system works

Comment: I'm having trouble making the links actually connect to any javascript. How do you link these via the routes.rb file? I've been researching this for a few days and can't find a straightforward answer.

Comment: Hoo boy. You'll have to give me more than that. When you click on the link, do you get the appropriate activity on the server? (You can observe the activity in your console.) If not, what's happening? If so, is it that nothing happens on the front end (in your browser) after you've clicked the link?

Comment: I apologize for being vague. Yes, there is activity that comes on my console but nothing changes on the page. I'm trying to change an image when the link is clicked. I don't understand how to actually activate the js. The activity appears to be rendering the same page again

Comment: This is probably a basic rails questions, because I'm not sure how to make any js work in a rails app in general. But for some reason I just can't find info on how to do this. Thank you very much

Comment: I do JS in a decidedly non-Rails way because I find the Rails way to be jenk. I never use `.js.erb` files and I turn turbolinks off on all my projects. So, I probably can't be much help to you. All I can say is read, read, read.